# Team foundation server compare function

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I am using visual studio 2013 and TFS.

There are several others which are working on same files so I constantly use the Compare function of source control.

I'm not an expert with `TFS` and may be wrong here, but if 2 files are identical `TFS` display both of files side by side anyway .

If this is the designed behavior, then infamous `Source Safe`  in this case had a better functionality and was displaying "`Files are identical`".

Is there an option which I can make TFS do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some message such as ’Files are identical’ would not be displayed when you are comparing two identical files using **Diff window**.

However, here are some tips helping you quickly get the result.

[image]

```
  1.Deleted text
  2.Added text
  3.Changed text
  4.Code review comment
  5.Visual summary of the differences between the files
```

So if you can’t see any flag in visual summary window,  you can judge two files are exactly the same.